# Xcode not able to find Firebase.h , React Native project

Tags: xcode, firebase, react-native-ios

I am trying to use react-native-firebase and has followed instructions from here https://rnfirebase.io/ .
While react native project could not find RNFirebase module, I decided to open Xcode project and then build it to see issues. I found Xcode is not able to find Firebase.h

I have pods installed correctly, I can see all firebase headers under Xcode. I have tried following 
1. Reinstalled updated Pods multiple times
2. Cleaned project and rebuilt
3. Deleted derived data a few times a tried
4. Added header search paths using PODS_ROOT constant and even tried with exact path of file but no avail.

I am not sure why its not working and what else needs to be done to get it working. I have Firebase/Core and Firebase/auth setup.
Xcode version being used is 10.

Any pointers would be helpful.

Edit:
I have tried things from this issue https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/198

Comment: A long time ago this: https://medium.com/@anum.amin/react-native-integrating-push-notifications-using-fcm-349fff071591 worked for me, maybe you will have some luck with it too. This was the most horrible thing I encountered when developing RN on ios, it only gets better from here.

Comment: Yes it is and I have dumped RN forever , this is not first time I am coming across such nonesense in case of RN.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the build system to "Legacy Build system" in Files > Project settings > Build system.
If it still doesn't work try closing and reopening Xcode. Its sometimes helps.

Comment: you can see my comments at the bottom , I tried all things from that thread nothing works .

Comment: Plese double check if you have followed all the steps in  https://rnfirebase.io/ or try unlinking  and linking again.

Comment: thing is that this issue is with Firebase SDK and not RNFirebase. So think its not related to linking if I am not wrong .